# Get the value of textbox after complete typing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Need to get the typed value after typing  using JavaScript but function not working.

my code:

```
<input onkeyup= "myfunction()" type="number" name="textboxname" value="">

<script>
  
 function myfunction()
 {
   alert($(this).val());
 }

</script>
```

Comment: pass here `this` as well `onkeyup = myfunction(this)` and then your function will look like : `function myfunction(el){alert($(el).val());}`

Comment: @Swati it is working, Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass to your function the value as a parameter

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="myfunction(this.value)">
<script>
function myfunction(value) {
    console.log(value)
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your input field
and use `$('#id').val()` function

So your code should be

```
<input onkeyup="myfunction()" id="my_id" type="number" name="textboxname">

  <script>

    function myfunction() {
      alert($('#my_id').val());
    }

  </script>
```